# Anomaly detection on one dimensional data

Tags: variance, outliers, sparse, anomaly-detection

I'm looking for a general method to detect outliers in one dimensional data. That is to say without setting any anomaly threshold.

Below is an example of my data :

[image]

Red points are far enough from the main group to be considered as outliers.

There are not a lot of data. I'm not sure if I can use something like variance or median absolute deviation since my data seems to don't fit any probability distribution.

Using something like k-means should be limited : I can get several main groups of points, therefore I can't set k.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Well, how did you arrive at the conclusion that the two red points are anomalous? What criteria do you use? There is a huge literature on outlier detection and you should get familiar with some of these papers.